# How to conect PgAdmin to RDS AWS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-rds, pgadmin-4

I have a private RDS Database which i was always conecting to with ssh tunel and terminal

For instance if i need to conect to it.

I just opened terminal and run this command to make SSH tunel

```
ssh -N -L 1234:********-**-****.***********.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 ec2-user@ec*-*-***-**-***.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com -i "************-dev.pem"
```

And then i open another terminal to conect to RDS database with psql like so:

```
psql -h localhost -U [username] -p 1234 [dbname]
```

But i can't understand already for a week how do i do it with pgAdmin client

[image]

In host name adres field i use this value

Database endpoint value - `********-**-****.***********.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com`

And port name is - 5432

Database username and password which are 100% corect.

But i always have same error

[image]

Maybe someone knows what am i doing wrong here.

It's 100% my mistake but where

Comment: You could establish the tunnel as you currently do for use with psql, and then just point PgAdmin at it (localhost:1234).  You can configure PgAdmin to create the tunnel for you, but that is not necessary.

Comment: @jjanes Do you mean conect PgAdmin to ssh tunel ?  But could you please tell how i do it in PgAdmin ?
Let's say i have ssh tunel 
ssh -N -L 1234:********-**-****.***********.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 ec2-user@ec*-*-***-**-***.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com -i "************-dev.pem"

Comment: You have shown us the image of a dialog box.  But it is empty, and it is the wrong one.  What is the point of showing us an empty dialog box?  The tab you need to fix is the one labelled 'SSH tunnel'.

Comment: @jjanes Because i couldn't show a real endpoints usernames and paswords which i use. But i thought it's not logical to insert there just a dummy values. As they are not correct anyway.
I just can'tunderstand what should be in those fields

Comment: To use the tunnel you made yourself, you just do the same thing you do for psql--put 'localhost' as host and '1234' as port

Comment: @jjanes Thank you, it worked.
Turns out to connect pgAdmin to ssh tunel i had to use localhost as host name in field.
And i use endpoint all the time.